# Can KStream.to() and StreamsBuilder.table() using the same topic and in the same StreamsBuilder in Kafka Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

As the title shows,Java Stream code like follow:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, City> citesStream = builder.stream("cities"
            , Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesFactory.serdesFrom(City.class)));
    citesStream.filter((name, city) -> city.getParentId() != 0).to("citiesExcludeProvince"
            , Produced.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesFactory.serdesFrom(City.class)));
    KTable<String, City> allCityTable = builder.table("citiesExcludeProvince"
            , Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesFactory.serdesFrom(City.class)));
```

I want filter some city and save to anther Kafka topic and then read it as a KTable for join as follow:

```
KStream<String, City> provinceStream = citesStream
            .filter((name, city) -> city.getParentId() == 0);
    provinceStream.leftJoin(allCityTable, (province, city) -> {
        System.out.println(JsonUtil.objectToJson(province));
        System.out.println(JsonUtil.objectToJson(city));
        if (province != null && city != null) {
            if (city.getParentId() == province.getId()) {
                if (province.getChildren() == null) {
                    province.setChildren(Lists.newArrayList());
                }
                province.getChildren().add(city);
            }
        }
        return province;
    }).to("provinceWithCity", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesFactory.serdesFrom(City.class)));
```

But i get the `citiesExcludeProvince` topic is alway empty.Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

> Can KStream.to() and StreamsBuilder.table() using the same topic and in the same StreamsBuilder in Kafka Stream?

Yes, you can use an input topic for `StreamsBuilder.table()` that is an output topic from `KStream.to().` `StreamsBuilder` doesn't allow certain types of cycles, but these—that run through some topic—are allowed. In this regard, I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.

---

> I want filter some city and save to anther Kafka topic and then read it as a KTable for join as follow ... But i get the citiesExcludeProvince topic is alway empty.Where is the error?

There are several problems with your code:

1. Cities that are arriving into the join are not keyed by province ID. So the join will never happen.
2. If the cities were keyed by province ID, every city that arrived to the table on the right would override any previous city that arrived on the right. This is because a table is a changelog of values by key. If there are multiple cities that belong to a province in a stream keyed by province ID, in the table you will only see the last one to arrive.
3. The right-side table doesn't trigger computation. This is a `KStream`-`KTable` join, and the semantics of such a join are the only events on the left cause processing. Events on the right are merely stored in the table. (On a related note, you can't really use `KStream`-`KTable` joins to process historical data. When you turn on your Kafka Streams application, it has a consumer that reads all your input topics. If it reads the topic that creates `provinceStream` before the contents of `allCityTable`, then your provinces won't find anything in the `allCityTable` because it will still be empty.)
4. The left-side will never be `null` (you don't have to do that check).

---

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
// Step 1

KTable<String, ArrayList<City>> citiesByProvince = citesStream
  .filter((name, city) -> city.getParentId() != 0)
  .groupBy((k, v) -> v.getParentId())
  .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
             (k, v, a) -> {
                 a.add(v);
                 return a;
             });

// Step 2

provinceStream
  .groupBy((k, v) -> v.getId())
  .reduce((a, b) -> a)
  .join(citiesByProvince, (province, cities) -> {
      province.setChildren(cities);
      return province;
  });
```

- Step 1: aggregate all cities by province ID into a list. The resulting list is keyed by province ID.
- Step 2: turn the provinces into a table keyed by province ID (you could do this equivalently by writing the contents of `provinceStream` to a topic and then using `StreamBuilder.table()`, but `groupBy()`->`reduce()` does the same thing here) and then performs the join.

Unlike your `KStream-KTable` join, the `KTable-KTable` join is not sensitive to the order in which records arrive from the underyling consumer, so you'll get deterministic results.

Comment: Hi!I define the `props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,  Serdes.String().getClass());`,but I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String` exception.

Comment: `KTable<String, ArrayList<City>> citiesByProvince = citiesStream.filter((name, city) -> city.getParentId() != 0)
                .groupBy((k, v) -> String.valueOf(v.getParentId()))
                .aggregate(ArrayList<City>::new, (k, v, a) -> {
                            a.add(v);
                            return a;
                        }, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), SerdesFactory.serdesFrom(ArrayList.class))
                );`  The `a.add()` tip can't resolve method.

Comment: 1) Not sure what's going on there. I never use the default serde setting. 2) Not sure what's going on here, this can be a little tricky for me sometimes and requires a bit of playing as many types are involves to get it right. My guess it the value serde type is off: `(SerdesFactory.serdesFrom(ArrayList.class))`, is it `Serde<List<City>>`?